# Why do I get "not a known element" error in Angular16

Tags: angular

Im building an Angular App where I have reusable components. And use Library like Angular-Mat  or PrimeNG. To keep AppModule as clean as possible I created a Module called Components which Contains the Modules Ui (for reusabel UI Components) and Pages (for Components who represent a Page). Each Component also is in its own Module for example my  Component toolbar-ui is in the ToolbarUiModule which is in the UiModule which is in ComponentsModule.[Screenshot of Filestructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2Oy0.png)

I tried to export ToolbarUiComponent in ToolbarUiModule which gets exported in UiModule. Then I import UiModule in HomePageModule to use it in HomePageComponent my IDE (VS Code) stops marking it as error after Import but when I ng serve ig the app-toolbar-ui is not a known element.

ToolbarUiModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ToolbarUiComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SidebarModule,
    DividerModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
  ],
  exports: [ToolbarUiComponent],
})
export class ToolbarUiModule {}
```

UiModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [ToolbarUiModule, PostUiModule, CommentUiModule],
})
export class UiModule {}
```

HomePageModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomePageComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, UiModule, MatIconModule, MatButtonModule],
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

I also tried importing ToolbarUiModule in HomePageModule but got the same error:

```
src/app/components/pages/home-page/home-page/home-page.component.html:2:3 - error NG8001: 'app-toolbar-ui' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-toolbar-ui' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-toolbar-ui' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

2   <app-toolbar-ui></app-toolbar-ui>
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/components/pages/home-page/home-page/home-page.component.ts:8:16
    8   templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HomePageComponent.
```

Comment: Where did you get the name `app-toolbar-ui` from?

Comment: @AndyRay its the selector in the component.ts file `selector: 'app-toolbar-ui'`